# How do I check HoneyComb or higher is running, and accordingly call a method for that Version?

Tags: android

For Android Versions 3.0 and higher, I want to call a certain method.
Is there a way to check if a certain method is available in the running Android Version?

To be more precise, my MinSDK is 7 (Android 2.1), TargetSDK is 8 (Android 2.2) and I need to test
if HoneyComb Android 3.0 or higher is running.
Depending on that, how can I call that HoneyComb method?

The second part of the question arises, because simply calling that HoneyComb method, will not compile, as I am building against 2.2.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

> To be more precise, my MinSDK is 7 (Android 2.1), TargetSDK is 8 (Android 2.2) and I need to test if HoneyComb Android 3.0 or higher is running. Depending on that, how can I call that HoneyComb method?

Step #1: Set your build target to the highest API level you wish to call directly and therefore compile against. Your build target (e.g., `compileSdkVersion` in Android Studio, Project > Properties > Android in Eclipse) is not related to your `android:targetSdkVersion`.

Step #2: As the other answers have indicated, you can then conditionally call methods within a guard block:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
  // call something for API Level 11+
}
```

> The second part of the question arises, because simply calling that HoneyComb method, will not compile, as I am building against 2.2.

You need to change your build target to be API Level 11 or higher if you wish to directly call API Level 11 or higher methods.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that `android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.*` members are replaced at compile time (iirc, right?), so he doesn't need to worry about `HONEYCOMB`, `HONEYCOMB_MR2` and so on not being available (i.e., defined) on systems running Gingerbread and below... he can check against them on previous systems.

Comment: Great tx, I was falsely assuming that the eclipe build target relates to android:targetVersion. Yipee!

Comment: The only thing which is less nice, is that this forces me to test on my HoneyComb tablet instead of my 2 mobile phones. Luckily, it is only a single statement, so I comment it out until the development is finished. I never use the emulator for testing, to slow...

Comment: The official Android emulator is very slow indeed.  I do testing with the BlueStacks emulator instead, it is much faster (running in debug mode is slower than in release mode, but it is still usable).

Answer (score 4):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= x ) {}
```

x is the api number, Honeycomb is 11
you can find api numbers here:
[Platform versions](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html)