# If-else statement based on OS Version in Android

Tags: android

Basically I want to run a code if the OS is Honeycomb or latter, and a different code if not. Should I compare using `>` or `>=` ?

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

} else {

}
```

Comment: since you want to include Honeycomb >=

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To use `HoneyComb` use `>=`

i.e. code as

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {

} else {

}
```

For more info see at [Android Check for HoneyComb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9959990/how-do-i-check-honeycomb-or-higher-is-running-and-accordingly-call-a-method-for)

Answer (score 3):

As per your requirement used `>=` means with `HoneyComb`

Comment: Thanks, I upvoted your answer but will accept Giru Bhai one because it was posted earlier